# How to access wampserver from public IP

Tags: windows, apache, wampserver

I had setup my wampserver and I'm not able to access it from my external IP. Note that wamp server is online and all services running.

On www.yougetsignal.com my port 8080 is open as you can see.

```
Port 8080 is open on 174.94.73.xxx
```

I opened the port in my windows firewall too. I'm using Bell Home Hub 2000 as my modem/router. Even in my modem the port is open and I redirect to my computer 192.168.2.15 for all incoming connections with this port.

In my httpd.conf I got the following

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
#I tried to add this line but nothing changed
#Listen 192.168.2.15:8080
#Tried this one too but wampserver can't start apache if I uncomment
#174.94.73.xxx:8080

ServerName 192.168.2.15:80
#I tried 192.168.2.15:8080 without success
```

http://localhost:8080/ is working

When typing in my browser my public IP (174.94.73.xxx:8080) I got an error that says Website can't be accessed. 174.94.73.xxx:8080 took too long to respond.

Few days ago, my website was working but when I changed my provider from videotron to Bell it stopped working. Since, I did a few changes and now I'm not sure how it was set before. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running???

Comment: Wampserver 3.0.4 with apache 2.4.18 (the kit on the wampserver website)